# Html Agility - Get Value by Name Tag

Tags: c#, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I need to get a value from an input, but the id always change, only the name is the same.
Didn't found anything on google to extract the value by the name tag.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="5aafaee2dd21555c2615fd26c0cccd0f1b2c3018" id="Token749368899" /></div>
```

I look forward to some answers.

Comment: There is no runat="sever" in your HTML. Then can you please tell why C# tag is used?

Comment: This is just an example of an input field. Also this is an desktop application and i need to parse a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input= doc.DocumentNode
              .Descendants("input")
              .First(n=>n.Attributes["name"].Value=="data[_Token][key]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the first part of Id, if it's always `Token#####`

```
//input[starts-with(@id, 'Token')]
```

Comment: Sorry that i forgot to say that, but there are 2 fields with difference tokens, same as in the example, only the name is different.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

var dummy = document.getElementsByName("data[_Token][key]");

This will return you elements which has name "data[_Token][key]".